# How do I animate a banner only using CSS, the timeline is messed up

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a banner using only CSS and no JS. If I were to use a JS library such as GreenSock or Create if would be easier to set the timing but I have no idea how to do it using only keyframes.

I have tried to set the opacity of the items in order to show the ones beneath but it's not working out.

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.banner{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
}

.first {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes first {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    50% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
  }

.first img {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 30%;
    animation-name: first-screen;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}

.bg {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
margin-top: -10%;
 overflow: hidden;
 object-fit: cover;
 object-position: center;
 animation-name: bg;
 animation-duration: 3s;
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes bg {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
  }

.offer{
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0
}

.copy {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    animation-name: copy;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 2s;

}

@keyframes copy {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    50% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
  }


.headline {
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 10%;
}

.subheadline {
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 22%;
}
```

I need the first-screen to fade in and that screen needs to show for two sec and fade away, immediately then the background will fade in in and last for three seconds while the copy also fade in at a different pace. In this case all my elements except the background end up showing at the end of the animation.

This is the html:

```
                <div class="first-screen"><img src="img/1st_frame.jpg"/></div>
                <div class="copy">
                    <img src="img/headline.png" class="headline"/>
                    <img src="img/subheadline.png" class="subheadline" />
                </div>
                <img src="img/offer.png" class="offer" />
                <img src="img/bg.jpg" class="bg"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried z-index?

Comment: Where is your html? You need to give people the tools to help you.

Comment: I updated the html but it's so simple I don't think it was necessary. I just need some help with chaining the animations through the timeline.

Comment: animation-fill-mode: forwards solves it?

Comment: I don't notice any difference applying animation-fill mode to any of the keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of fix it by setting the same duration for all the animations and then using percents to show and hide the items but still there are elements that should show up and fade at the same time and have different timing even though the CSS keyframes and properties are the same. The bg and the headlines should both fade at the same time instead only the headlines fade. Does anyone know why?

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.interstitial {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
}

.first {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.first img {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 30%;
    animation-name: first-screen;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes first {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    20% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    40% {
        opacity: 0
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.bg {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: -20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    animation-name: bg;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    z-index: 0
}

@keyframes bg {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.offer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.copy {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    animation-name: headlines;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes headlines {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}


.headline {
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 10%;
}

.subheadline {
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 22%;
}
```